# How would temperature variation work on the inside surface of a Dyson sphere?

Tags: geography, temperature, dyson-spheres

Let's say I have a Dyson sphere roughly the same size of the earth with a very small "star" in the center. Continents, oceans, and people inside the sphere experience a reverse gravity in the opposite direction as the the star.

The star's output power(heat and light) is directly proportional to the equation `1 + sin(t*2pi/d)/2 + sin(t*2pi/y)/2` where `t` is time in seconds, `d` is the length of a day, and `y` is the length of a year in seconds.

Given all of this, how would I make it so that the inside of the sphere experiences similar temperature distribution as the real Earth? Such that, reverse-Florida is hot, and Antarctica is cool.

Comment: Why is the "star's" luminosity periodic? Is it undergoing dramatic pulsations? I think you'll also need to specify the luminosity, radius, temperature, etc. of that body.

Comment: The power is periodic because night and day. I'm not sure those other terms matter

Comment: If the star's in the center, though, I don't see how there could *be* a night and a day. The inside should always be facing the light.

Comment: Night is a trough of the second term. Day is a crest of the second term.

Comment: Right, but I'm asking if there's a reason for the brightness increasing and decreasing, and I'm also asking how that scales - in other words, what unit it's in. If I plug in $t=0$, I get 1, but I don't know what that "1" means, in terms of units.

Comment: The function itself is unitless, but you multiply it by an amplitude over 2, which has your desired units.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. But you haven't made it clear what that amplitude is.

Comment: You're right. I haven't.

Comment: «people inside the sphere experience a reverse gravity in the opposite direction as the the star.»  how do you manage that?  No matter what you do, the opposite side will cancel out and you feel zero gravity towards the shell on the inside.

Comment: @JDługosz I presume the star has a negative gravitation. The Newtonian cancellation of gravitation inside a hollow sphere doesn't apply. Living on the inside of the dyson sphere is as if gravity holds them down. If this is an artificial Hollow Earth scenario, with a time-varying central 'star' to give a day-and-night cycle & negative gravitation keeping everything on the inner surface of the dyson sphere. Minimal 'magic' makes it work. :)

Comment: A negative gravity star? And it doesn't blow itself apart?  IAC answering the question with *magic* is just a cop-out. He could have written that without having to pose the question.

Comment: @JDługosz Actually if the entire star had negative gravitational mass it would pull itself together but blow everything else away. You wouldn't be able to orbit it though, in fact getting the sphere into place unless it's also made from negative mass would be very tricky.

Comment: Gravity is bipolar in this universe. There are periods of negative and positive gravity.

Comment: @OneNormalNight what are you talking about?

Comment: @timb sounds like you are describing something like electric charge. But that doesn't work in GR: a spacetime geodesic affects anything passing through it in the same way, and simply cannot seem like different geometry to different charged objects.

Comment: Things that are largely irrelevant to the initial question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heat escapes to the outside at the "poles".

This gives an effect of being cold near the poles, while hot near equatorial places.

Answer (score 1):

Energy in equals energy out. So you want different parts of the inner surface to have different temperatures? Shift one side of the equation. Energy out probably comes from black body radiation to the outside, or sending energy somewhere else like through wires or something.

To get rid of more energy near your cold places, radiate it to the outside, maybe by increasing the exterior surface area perhaps by adding fins. The sun would still be as strong in the hot places as cold places, paint your igloo black and you have a sauna.

To absorb less energy make the colder places be farther from the star, you say Dyson *sphere*, but what if it's kinda oblique? The farther the surface is from the star the less it energy per square meter. A flat spot might create cold places by the difference between x and sin(x). Might look kinda lumpy from the outside though.

Or you could put sunblockers between the surface and the star. This might ruin some peoples view of your star, and do remember Mr Burn got shot when he tried it.

Answer (score 0):

depends how solid it is, if your dyson sphere is a near heatproof wall then you have an interesting question, because you would have a pressure cooker.

However, if its anything like the dyson sphere in [Peter F Hamilton's commonwealth saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga) (which was a modified forcefield), that allows all light out by red-shifting it into infrared, then nothing changes to normal, beyond limitation of resources.

Comment: Can you explain that more? If it’s only a pointer to the novel, then it ought to be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to not make it a perfect sphere.  Earth is actually an oblate spheroid so it is not a stretch to make your thing a prolate (elongated) spheroid.  This would cause the poles of your sphere to be further away from your mini-star, while the center ring is closer to it.  This should cause the temperatures to be warmer near the center and colder near the poles.